# Using Facebook iOS SSO for a wrapped web app?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on, oauth-2.0

I'm building an iPad optimized html5 web app which I am going to wrap (& distribute) in a native app container.

For some social features I'd like to make use of the Facebook SSO and was wondering if I can use the SSO of the Facebook iOS SDK and "forward" (& use) the access token to my web app. If this is possible, how could I trigger the log-out from a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for you to use the Facebook SSO to get the access token and forward the token to any other part of your app.  Their API won't distinguish the difference between a call from a native device and any other client.

We do this already in the Socialize SDK (http://www.getsocialize.com).  In order to verify the validity of the tokens received by the client we test them with server-side code.